# Fastest `where` request involving three models in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, postgresql

I'm having a little trouble with a slow page load in Rails, I'm certain due to the way I'm querying the database (PostgreSQL).

To summarise the situation, I've three models - let's call them `Model A`, `Model B` and `Model C` - that I'm plugging into a table, and am struggling to find an efficient way to query the data.

`Model A` provides the table's header row, `Model B` each row in the `tbody`; `Model C` belongs to both `Model A` and `Model B` and provides the table data.

Here's a quick example:

Say the model variables are as follows:

```
@model_a = ModelA.all
@model_b = ModelB.all
@model_c = ModelC.all
```

Related as follows:

```
class ModelA

  has_many :model_cs

end

class ModelB

  has_many :model_cs

end

class ModelC

  belongs_to :model_a
  belongs_to :model_b

end
```

And in the view:

```
<table>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <!-- Model A provides the table headers -->
      <% @model_a.each do |a| %>
        <th>
          <%= a.name %>
        </th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <!-- Each row represents a different instance of Model B -->
    <% @model_b.each do |b| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= b.name %>
        </td>
        <% @model_a.each do |a| %>
          <td>
            <!-- The actual table data is from Model C, when it belongs to both Model A and Model B -->
            <% if (c = @model_c.where(model_a_id: a.id, model_b_id: b.id).first).present? %>
              <%= c.name %>
            <% end %>
          </td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Obviously this is really slow and, I'd imagine, rather stinky code. I can cache the fragment, but would much rather speed up the request so it runs smoothly following any changes to the data. Happy to consider different approaches to this - I just can't think of a way to present the data in this manner without iterating through two models to query the third.

I'm sure there's a far, *far* better way to approach this but have yet to come up with it. Hope you guys can help - thanks in advance, Steve.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that defines `@model_a`, `@model_b`, and `@model_c`.

Comment: Hi Jordan - have done. I've also added the way they're related. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view, this code will run a new SQL query each table cell:

```
@model_c.where(model_a_id: a.id, model_b_id: b.id).first
```

So that's probably what's really hurting you. Remember that `where` is part of ActiveRecord and goes to the database, whereas `select` operates on enumerables and does everything in memory.

You should load everything with the right relationships upfront. I would start with this:

```
@model_a = ModelA.all
@model_b = ModelB.includes(:model_cs)
```

Then do this:

```
<tbody>
  <!-- Each row represents a different instance of Model B -->
  <% @model_b.each do |b| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= b.name %>
      </td>
      <% @model_a.each do |a| %>
        <td>
          <!-- The actual table data is from Model C, when it belongs to both Model A and Model B -->
          <% if c = b.model_cs.select{|x| x.model_a_id = a.id}.first %>
            <%= c.name %>
          <% end %>
        </td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

That should get you everything in two or three queries.

Note if A is large, the `select` will still perform poorly because it does a linear search. So you could write a method on your ModelB class like this instead, and use it in the view:

```
def model_c_for(a)
  @model_c_by_a ||= Hash[
    model_cs.map{|c| [c.model_a_id, c]}
  ]
  @model_c_by_a[a.id]
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the input Paul. This makes perfect sense and is exactly the approach I was looking for, *but* it actually slows the request by about 10 seconds. Unusual right? I've benchmarked the two queries and yours is consistently faster as a one off (~ 1.6s v 2.5s). Implementing your methodology cuts down the ActiveRecord load time tenfold (5s - 500ms), though increases the view rendering by about 15s; exactly the opposite of what I'd expected to see. What do you think? Again, thanks again for your help here, I read it and thought 'yep, spot on!'.

Comment: I assume you have indexes already on all foreign key columns? How large are A and B? If B is large, consider paginating. If A is large, see the update I made to the answer. If A is very large, I would find a way not to render all columns every time, but let users choose what they want to see.

Comment: Also if both A and B are very large, I would consider bypassing ActiveRecord here and just writing a SQL query. As long as you're using  AR, it's going to be costly instantiating all those ModelCs. Since you'll have a variable number of columns (one for each ModelA), this article mibht help: http://illuminatedcomputing.com/posts/2013/03/fun-postgres-puzzle/

Comment: That's great, thanks so much for the guidance. I will take your advice and implement as above - I think a SQL query will prove the best approach.